# Issue with Gantt Chart zooming in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, gantt-chart

We are using radiantq library to display the gantt chart in our silverlight application. There is a feature where the chart and the time scale zooms when you scroll with mouse wheel. After the zoom, the start date and end date are recomputed based on the zoom level. This works fine. But when I move to another page and come back to the same page again, the zoom level is reset to default since chart is constructed again. But when I move the tasks in the chart the start and end dates are calculated wrongly based on the previous zoom level that was set previously though the size is correct.
   My suspicion is that one of the property that was changed when I zoomed previously has not changed after the gantt is constructed again. I couldn't find the property though. Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: Could you tell us how exactly you reconstruct the gantt? Are your creating a new instance of the gantt or just resetting properties on it? If so, what properties?

Is the gantt inside a tab by any chance?

Comment: This issue was fixed by upgrading to the latest version of radiantq. I got help from the support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by upgrading to the latest version of radiantq. We were using 4.0.4.1. Now, we upgraded to the latest version.